# How to set the value of textarea in symfony

Tags: symfony

I am getting a url variable via GET on my controller and want to set it as value of my textarea. Here's my textarea line:

```
{{ form.myTextArea is defined ? form_row(form.myTextArea) }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{{ form_row(form.myTextArea, {'value': 'your text'}) }}
```

Comment: Is it value or data? As the textarea doesn't have a value attribute

Comment: this is not as an attribute of text input , to add an attribute we use {'attr': {'attr_name': value }}, is that ?

Comment: if you want to fill it with variable, just pass it in place of 'your text' without  ''